# Just generate path for a temporary file

Tags: python, python-2.7

As `tempfile.mktemp` is depreciated in Python 2.7 I generate a unique path to a temporary file as follows:

```
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".py")
path_to_generated_py = temp.name
temp.close()
# now I use path_to_gerated_py to create a python file
```

Is this the recommended way in Python 2.7? As I close the temp file immediately it looks like misusing `NamedTemporaryFile`....

Comment: I think it is an OK way.  But why don't you just hang onto the file handle and use it directly?

Comment: .. because I'm using a third party library which requires a path.

Comment: My https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shelljob library also has a simple way to create named temporaries that are delete after a `with` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct replacement for `tempfile.mktemp()` is `tempfile.mkstemp()`.  The latter creates the file, like `NamedTemporaryFile`, so you must close it (as in your code snippet).  The difference with `NamedTemporaryFile` is that the file is not deleted when closed.  This is actually required: your version has a theoretical race condition where two processes might end up with the same temporary file name.  If you use `mkstemp()` instead, the file is never deleted, and will likely be overwritten by the 3rd-party library you use --- but at any point in time, the file exists, and so there is no risk that another process would create a temporary file of the same name.